# multiple colors in smoothbar theme

Tags: beamer, themes, navigation

I'm currently working on a customized beamer theme, and I decided that I like the `smoothbars` theme a lot. However, what I'd like to change is that I want the bar itself to be split in several horizontal compartments, one per section, with every section having a different color selected from a cycle, instead of the entire bar being unicolor.

As I figured that this would require me looking into the actual code of the `smoothbars` theme, this is what I did.

I started with looking in the code and finding the line

```
\insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
```

which expands to an expression with a wealth of skipping and boxing commands, but also contains

```
\dohead
```

which then expands to a loop

```
\beamer@headcounter =0\relax 
\loop 
\ifnum \beamer@headcounter <\beamer@totalheads \advance\beamer@headcounter by1\relax
\csname @@head\the \beamer@headcounter \endcsname
\repeat
```

Naively, I thought that this loop would run over the sections and just print the section titles in some box environment, so I looked at the contents of `\csname @@head\the \beamer@headcounter \endcsname`.
Interestingly, these precisely expand to the contents of the lines of the `*.nav` file, for example

```
\sectionentry {1}{Introduction}{2}{Introduction}{0}
```

which sort of makes sense, given how the `.nav` file contains all the necessary information - but I'm confused by the fact that not only the section headings, but all sorts of other things turn up as well, like

```
\beamer@framepages {1}{1}
```

or

```
\beamer@sectionpages {1}{1}
\beamer@subsectionpages {1}{1}
```

I don't really understand what is going on here. What is the most sensible part to intervene in order to change the background color of the `smoothbar` behind every section in a cycle of, say, 5 different colors?

## Edit

As requested, here is an MWE. It's not really an MWE in the sense that it produces the problem, as I just don't understand what's going on well enough to make any serious attempt at getting the coloring right. However, I don't understand why uncommenting the `\colorbox` command results in the layout being completely disrupted, so this might be a good place to start.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\makeatletter
% this code is the result of me collecting the bits & pieces
% from the macro definitions in `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty`
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{smoothbars theme}{%
    \vbox {%
      \beamer@xpos =0\relax \beamer@ypos=1\relax
      \hbox to \paperwidth{
        % this is some spacing that I don't really understand what it does
        \hskip .3cm\setbox\beamer@sectionbox =\hbox {\kern 1sp}
        \hskip -1.875ex plus-1fill
        \global \beamer@section@min@dim \z@
        % loop over the entries of the *.nav file
        \beamer@headcounter =0\relax
        \loop
        \ifnum \beamer@headcounter <\beamer@totalheads\advance \beamer@headcounter by1\relax
        % I would have expected that putting a 'colorbox' here would do the trick of coloring the individual section headings
        % however, very strange things happen when uncommenting the following line, which probably has to do with the fact
        % that the loop runs over 17 entries (instead of just 2, as I would have expected)
        %\colorbox{red}{ 
          \csname @@head\the \beamer@headcounter \endcsname
        %}
        \repeat
        % some more spacing commands
        \beamer@section@set@min@width \box \beamer@sectionbox
        \hfil \hskip .3cm
      }
    }
}%
\makeatother

% now comes some dummy code just to have some slides to look at
\title{Hello World}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Hello!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Further stuff}

\begin{frame}{Hello!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a MWE in order to give us something to start with?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added an MWE, if you want to call it like that :-) I hope somebody can make me understand what's happening here :-)

Comment: What is the purpose of the additional package you tried to edit in?

Comment: It doesn't compile for me without it, as it defines the `\pretocmd` command.

Comment: With pdflatex from texlive 2016 I had no problems.

Comment: Strange, I'm also using pdflatex from texlive 2016...

Comment: See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35275014#35275014. The mystery is solved, `beamer` now already loads `etoolbox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why didn't I discover `colorseries` earlier? They are really handy!

The following assumes sections of a similar length:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usecolortheme{orchid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{series=\bfseries}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black, bg=}

\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolorseries{foo}{rgb}{last}{red}{blue}
\resetcolorseries[3]{foo}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\number\totvalue{totalsection}}{%
            {\color{foo!![\i]}\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth/\number\totvalue{totalsection}\relax}{7ex}}%
    }
  \vskip-7ex%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[ignorebg,ht=2.25ex,dp=3.75ex]{section in head/foot}
    \insertnavigation{\paperwidth}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{totcount}

\newcounter{totalsection}
\regtotcounter{totalsection}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \pretocmd{\section}{\refstepcounter{totalsection}}{\typeout{Yes, prepending was successful}}{\typeout{No, prepending was not it was successful}}%
}%

\title{Hello World}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}{Hello!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Further stuff}

\begin{frame}{Hello!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{some stuff}

\begin{frame}{Hello!}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello!
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]