# Access a given colors from a preset array

Tags: color, variable

I use a variation of the BlueBox chapter style in order to change the header color with each new chapter. 
For now i have to set the new color before each new chapter wich is not optimal.

I wanted to know if there is a method to create a list/dictonary (not sure of the terminology in LaTex) callable with an external variable ?

Here is a snipet of a code that would allow me to do this in Python as an illustration :

```
x = 0
myColors = ['blue','green','red','purple']
color=myColors[x]
```

Setting the color to blue.

PS : if necessary i can provide a full example of the document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Continious colours:

If the colours can be expressed as a series between two colours, you could use this approach: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/352525/36296

## Non-continuous colours:

In this case you could include the numbering in the colour names. This makes it easy to select the colour based on chapter number.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{col1}{green}
\colorlet{col2}{red}
\colorlet{col3}{blue}

\begin{document}

\chapter{title}
{\color{col\thechapter} \rule{1em}{1em} }

\chapter{title}
{\color{col\thechapter} \rule{1em}{1em} }

\chapter{title}
{\color{col\thechapter} \rule{1em}{1em} }

\end{document}
```